# Past participle followed by past simple/perfect

Tags: past-participles

I've quite a specific question regarding participle clauses. I recently wrote:

> "**Having painted what he bothered**, John began packing his brushes."

Or should it be:

> "**Having painted what he had bothered**, John began packing his brushes."

Even though the first example sounds better; logically, John firstly had been bothered to paint the bare walls, and after that he started packing.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: The clauses in bold are meaningless and unnatural at best, and ungrammatical at worst. How can you say "He painted the thing(s) that he bothered"? Think about it.

Comment: The second one sounds a little better to me, although both are a little odd.  If I interpret you correctly, you mean "He painted as much as he bothered to"?

Comment: @stangdon Yes, like in the idiom "I cannot be bothered," well, John could be bothered, but only with painting some of it.

Comment: @PaulM After rereading those sentences for about 20min, I can see how the statements are confusing. Anyone has an idea how to rewrite it without loosing past participle or its whole meaning?

Comment: One way would be to say: _Having painted what he wanted, John began packing up his brushes_.

Comment: If you really want to include the word "bothered", you could say _Having painted only what/the bits he could be bothered to paint, Johns began packing up his brushes_

Comment: @PaulM Thank you for the examples, but the question somewhat stands; Doesn't it sound better: "Having painted what he _had_ wanted, John began packing up his brushes."

Comment: No. "John painted what he wanted, so he began..." etc. Not "John painted what he *had wanted*, so he began..." etc. Do you hear the difference?

Comment: I think the past perfect "had wanted" is inappropriate here. "Want" is not really anterior to "paint"; the two situations are contemporaneous.

Comment: @Jakub - I understand what you're trying to say; I think that the way you've chosen to phrase it is a little non-standard, and that's why it's confusing.  I would have said, "Having painted **as much as he could be bothered to**..."  because the phrase is *to bother **to** *, and because we're talking about an amount of what John could be bothered to do.

Comment: @Jakub It is time to invoke _FumbleFingers's Perfect Truism:_  **”Don’t use the perfect unless you need it.”** I would phrase it as: _Having painted what he pleased..._

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I have only myself as a judge, and I certainly haven't become dumber, quite the opposite really, so I guess question's purpose served. I have yet to unlock upvoting on ell, so sorry for that.

Comment: First, you need a grammatical sentence, then you can talk about tenses. The incorrect use of bother is bothersome.

Answer (score 1):

*Bother* has a couple of meanings, one is "to disturb", and *bother with X* or *bother to X* means "to do X given that X is considered a non-required or unimportant task".

> "Having painted what he bothered, John began packing his brushes."

This sentence really sounds like you are saying he is painting a person or thing that he disturbed.

You can add the preposition "to" or "with" afterward to clarify this.  *To* is probably the best choice.

> "Having painted what he bothered to, John began packing his brushes."

The rules for using perfect or non-perfect tenses in the first phrase are the same as if you were writing a full sentence, the fact that things are a participle phrase (it's not really a clause) doesn't change anything.

Without the *had*, you are giving the impression John left right after he got bored with painting.  With the *had*, there may have been something happening in between that you talked about earlier or will later talk about.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you're saying that fragment: "John having painted what he had wanted..." functions much in the same way as statement: "John had painted what he had wanted," is that right? Doesn't it contradict what @PaulM said in his comment(?): **I think the past perfect "had wanted" is inappropriate here. "Want" is not really anterior to "paint..."**

Comment: Having painted what he bothered with or without to is skimming the surface of what is not grammatical. It really doesn't make sense.